# Get Current User before ADFS authentication

Tags: c#, authentication, sharepoint, adfs, httpmodule

I'm currently writing an `HttpModule` in the hopes of gleaning the currently logged in user and redirecting them if they are trying to authenticate with the Windows credentials instead of using a valid ADFS claim/credentials.

So far, I've tried the following:

```
SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser;
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity;
```

I'm also looking at the IClaimsIdentity claims and the HttpRequest.Params.

What I've found is that because there are a few redirects in the authentication process, the module gets hit multiple times (PreRequestHandlerExecute event). I have also found that until the result is received from ADFS, the `SPContext` and `HttpContext` users are null. The `WindowsIdentity` user is 'NT AUTHORITY\IUSR' until it hits ADFS, where it is changed to the correct account if using IE and the settings are saved.

Is there a way to know (before ADFS is even involved) the user that will be sent over to get a claim? I figured it would be in the HttpRequest but so far I have found nothing. I'm interested in accessing the user so I can redirect if necessary and force a logout/login using valid credentials so that I can prevent the Windows accounts from ever being used for authentication. It seems like the `WindowsIdentity` is the right path but if it's always going to be the same that's not particularly helpful.

Comment: did you tried with **httpmodule** ? full source code with `PreRequestHandlerExecute event` ?